# Cocos2d angle confusion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

This system is really confusing me. I'm rotating a turret to face an enemy sprite, I get the angle in radians with:

```
float angleRadians = atanf(yDifference / xDifference);
float angleDegrees = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angleRadians);
```

That's cool, now I put the enemy in several positions to see how it plotted the angles in DEGREES:

T = Turret

```
-45      90      45

-0        T       0

45       -90     -45
```

The angle for an enemy top-right of the turret is going to be the same as the angle for an enemy bottom-left, thus I'd have to have some form of condition to distinguish the 2. That wouldn't be hard except for the fact that cocos2d's rotational angles work like this:

```
45      90        135

0       T       +/-180

-45    -90       -135
```

What do I have to do to convert the angle I calculated at the start to correctly rotate the turret with this system above?

Comment: You will get better results if you use atan2f(yDifference, xDifference)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use:

```
float angleRadians = atan2f(yDifference, xDifference);
```

this should return an angle in radians which is in the range [-pi, pi].
This should fix yoUr problem.